# Filtering the list of html links using a specific key word using Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, filtering

I am trying to extract the links using a specific work in each link in the list of links. Below is the code that I get the URLs:

```
import urllib

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs    
url ='https://fbref.com/en/squads/b8fd03ef/Manchester-City-Stats'
html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = bs(html_page, "html.parser")
links = []
player_link =[]
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))
```

From the above lines of code, I can store the list of links in the variable **links**
I want to create a new list containing only the specific word **summary**.
The expected output ( only part of all) that should be stored in a new list **player_list** is shown below:

```
 player_list =['/en/players/3bb7b8b4/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Ederson-Match-Logs',
    '/en/players/3eb22ec9/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Bernardo-Silva-Match-Logs',
    '/en/players/bd6351cd/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Joao-Cancelo-Match-Logs',
    '/en/players/31c69ef1/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Ruben-Dias-Match-Logs',
    '/en/players/6434f10d/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Rodri-Match-Logs',
    '/en/players/119b9a8e/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Aymeric-Laporte-Match-Logs']
```

I tried exploring some of the previous posts, but it did not work out. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for a condition (whether the link is non-empty and has `summary` in it):

```
out = [x for x in links if x and 'summary' in x]
```

Output:

```
['/en/players/3bb7b8b4/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Ederson-Match-Logs',
 '/en/players/3eb22ec9/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Bernardo-Silva-Match-Logs',
 '/en/players/bd6351cd/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Joao-Cancelo-Match-Logs',
 '/en/players/31c69ef1/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Ruben-Dias-Match-Logs',
 '/en/players/6434f10d/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Rodri-Match-Logs',
...
 '/en/players/02aed921/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Cieran-Slicker-Match-Logs',
 '/en/players/c19a2df1/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Josh-Wilson-Esbrand-Match-Logs']
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to filter your list in the end would be to select your targets more specific and filter from beginning - Following `list comprehension` selects only the `<a>` with summary in it and concat it with your baseUrl:

```
['https://fbref.com'+e['href'] for e in soup.select('a[href*="summary"]')]
```

##### Example

```
import urllib

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs    
url ='https://fbref.com/en/squads/b8fd03ef/Manchester-City-Stats'
html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = bs(html_page, "html.parser")
    
summaryUrls = ['https://fbref.com'+e['href'] for e in soup.select('a[href*="summary"]')]
print(summaryUrls)
```

###### Output

```
['https://fbref.com/en/players/3bb7b8b4/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Ederson-Match-Logs',
 'https://fbref.com/en/players/3eb22ec9/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Bernardo-Silva-Match-Logs',
 'https://fbref.com/en/players/bd6351cd/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Joao-Cancelo-Match-Logs',
 'https://fbref.com/en/players/31c69ef1/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Ruben-Dias-Match-Logs',
 'https://fbref.com/en/players/6434f10d/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Rodri-Match-Logs',
 'https://fbref.com/en/players/119b9a8e/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Aymeric-Laporte-Match-Logs',
 'https://fbref.com/en/players/ed1e53f3/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Phil-Foden-Match-Logs',
 'https://fbref.com/en/players/86dd77d1/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Kyle-Walker-Match-Logs',
 'https://fbref.com/en/players/b400bde0/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Raheem-Sterling-Match-Logs',
 'https://fbref.com/en/players/e46012d4/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Kevin-De-Bruyne-Match-Logs',
 'https://fbref.com/en/players/b0b4fd3e/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Jack-Grealish-Match-Logs',
 'https://fbref.com/en/players/819b3158/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Ilkay-Gundogan-Match-Logs',
 'https://fbref.com/en/players/b66315ae/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Gabriel-Jesus-Match-Logs',
 'https://fbref.com/en/players/892d5bb1/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/Riyad-Mahrez-Match-Logs',
 'https://fbref.com/en/players/5eecec3d/matchlogs/2021-2022/summary/John-Stones-Match-Logs',...]
```